# vagrant private network fails to resolve on windows 10 host

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

I can't get anything to work. I have windows 10 as my host and my guest VM is centos/7 box. It works great with forwarded_ports but using private_network setting nothing resolves. I'm not sure what to do or check

vagrant file look like

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/centos-7.4"
  config.vm.synced_folder "./website", "/var/www/html/", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=777"], owner: "apache", group: "apache"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
  ## Bootstrap script to provision box.  All installation methods can go here. 
  config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
    s.path = "bootstrap.sh"
  end
end
```

My ifconfig on guest looks like
[image]

My virtualbox shows two adapters

[image]
[image]

I get nothing when I browse to the IP on windows
[image]

Comment: Nobody uses vagrant anymore?

Comment: True devs dont run on windows ! (take it as a joke)

Comment: can you ping the VM ? can you run a `curl` command see if its not an issue with your browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually had nothing to do with vagrant. It was all set up correctly, but my magento site had a weird error. Thanks to Frederic for taking the time!